# Java SE7 concurrency - data not reaching AtomicReference<Map...>

Tags: java, concurrency

Still trying to get this thread/currency thing down. Thank you for your help.
The program is in three classes, Analysis which opens a file, takes a line from the file and passes it to a runnable class using a ForkJoinPool, then waits for the pool to finish and then outputs the data to another file, RowCheck is the runnable which sorts the data and then passes it to Data, the final class, which has an AtomicReference>> to organize the data before output.
Analysis:

```
threadmgmt.execute(thread);
...close loop...close try block...exception handling...
while(threadmgmt.hasQueuedSubmissions()){ }
        while(Data.isBusy()){
    if(threadmgmt.isQuiescent()){
        Data.setBusy(false); }   }
...try block for output...
output = Data.getArray(); // This is where the error is called from

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.hcue.csvanalysis.Data.getArray(Data.java:56)
at com.hcue.csvanalysis.Analysis.main(Analysis.java:55)
```

No surprise that it is a NullPointerException as the AtomicReference isn't being touched, though RowCheck gets to the point of calling the method to do so across sixty-something threads before. What suggests do you have?

Comment: You're not showing nearly enough code for us to identify your problem. Can you show `Data.getArray` at the very least?

Comment: Gladly... Data.getArray:

Comment: Gladly... Data.getArray:                                                         `public static Map<String, List<Integer>> getArray(){
     Map<String, List<Integer>> answer = new HashMap<>();
     Map<String, List<Integer>> temp = data.get();
     HashSet<String> collection = (HashSet<String>)temp.keySet();
     for(String iteration : collection){
         answer.put(iteration, temp.get(iteration));
     }
     return answer;
    }`